# How to get value from a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm working on SHT11 sensor with two streams as input and must be combined together to represent readable information. Say the humidity and temperature are declared as below:

```
uint8_t humi[3] = {};
uint8_t temp[3] = {};
```

and is combined by a pointer, `ptrFlash`:

```
uint8_t* ptrFlash;
```

In function writing the data packet:

```
ptrFlash = (uint8_t*)&writepkt->humi_data;
ptrFlash[0] = humi[0];
ptrFlash[1] = humi[1];
ptrFlash = (uint8_t*)&writepkt->temp_data;
ptrFlash[0] = temp[0];
ptrFlash[1] = temp[1];
```

In this case, both the humidity and temperature readings are assigned correctly. How do I extract the float/int reading from here? Is this from `writepkt` structure or `ptrFlash`? Structure of writepkt is as below:

```
typedef nx_struct DAT {
nx_uint8_t  nodeid;
nx_uint8_t  forwardid;
nx_uint8_t  destid;
nx_uint32_t pktid; 
nx_uint16_t humi_data;
nx_uint16_t temp_data;
nx_uint16_t intBatt_val;
nx_uint16_t extBatt_val;
nx_uint8_t  rssi_val;
nx_uint32_t total_pkt_num;
nx_uint8_t  immediate_parent_node;
nx_uint32_t node_fail_to_send_count;
nx_uint8_t  fan1_val;
nx_uint8_t  fan2_val;
} DAT;
```

Comment: Your question has no mention of any "`float/int` data"  and no data format definition. We don't have to dig in the datasheet of the sensor to find it out. Post all of the relevant information.

Comment: Sorry that I'm new in hardware. I've search through the datasheet and I'm not sure what kind of information is needed. I just want to extract the information (should be 16 bits) as float/int for comparison.

Comment: There is no such format `int/float`. It's either one or the other. And floats are 32bit minimum. The data representation should be well documented in the datasheet, so I believe once you read it, you will be able to answer the question yourself.

Comment: The sensor does probably not provide floats but rather ints, but this should be clearly stated on the datasheet. And please what the type of  `writepkt` ?

Comment: Yea I mean int or float, from what I found and to my best understanding from datasheet is an example, given by 0000’0100“0011’0001” = 1073 = 35.50%RH, this is what you meant?

Comment: Michael Walz, the writepkt is a self-defined packet structure. Humidity and temperature are part of the members in this packet structure.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Some sensors/etc. use their own floating point format. That could well be 16 bits.

Comment: Such sensors often generate fixed-point formats. You should stick with that (or convert to a common base fixed-point). I'd recommend to first get the terms clear for yourself, before asking. Often, you will find the solution yourself after you really know what you actually need/want.

Comment: nx_uint16_t humi_data;
     nx_uint16_t temp_data;   Well, it says in the definition that `humi_data` and `temp_data` are both integers.

I don't understand why you need to write only one byte at a time to the flash though. Are you saying you can write the values to the sensor but don't read them?  I am not sure what you are asking, honestly.

Comment: @Prof.Falken: proper serialization? Just sending the byte-layout is most times the wrong way. Think of endianess, padding/alignment for structs.

Comment: @Olaf, true, I didn't think about that. In that case the code should probably take into account endianness. But sure, that could be it and if for a specific micro controller which has a certain endianness and lots of code is hardware dependent anyway, fine.

Comment: @Prof.Falken: Only if the system is _very_ restricted and only for trivial types. Burried deep (and well-commented) in a distinct module. But once you have the ROM space, correct serialization is the way. Have a look at [nanopb](http://koti.kapsi.fi/~jpa/nanopb/docs/index.html)

Comment: I mean that the serialization above which does not take account of endianness is OK. Not going with serialization at all, which as you point out, has very limited uses. Basically, we are in "violent agreement". :)  Anyway, I am still not 100% sure what OP is asking/having trouble with, to get back on topic.

Comment: @Prof.Falken: Agreed (on all, especially the last sentence - reason for close-vote). I hope OP is currently busy thinking.